# What does it mean when we say "the line x=2 y=5" etc in multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Whilst studying my textbook, i came across the following notation: the line $x=2,y=3$. How does one graph that simple line out of two coordinates? I mean, in ordinary one-variable calculus it is very often used to say "the line $x=2$" or "the line $y=-13$". But how, in the three variable coordinate system can a line be graphed from knowing $2/3$ of the coordinates $(x=c_1,y=c_2$ or $z=c_1,x=c_2$ etc$)$?

Any thoughs appreciated!

Comment: I presume this is the line $\{(2,3,z):z\in\mathbb R\}$ - you get different points on the line by varying the $z$ coordinate. You can imagine a point $(2,3)$ on the $x,y$ plane, and then a line parallel to the $z$ axis going through that point.

Comment: Yes,that's it!Thanks for the really fast reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, $z$ is unconstrained, so this is the line $(2,3,z)$, $z\in\mathbb R$.

Geometrically, the equations $x=2$ and $y=3$ define a pair of planes. The line is the intersection of these planes. More generally, we could say something like “the line $a_1x+b_1y+c_1z+d_1=0$, $a_2x+b_2y+c_2z+d_2=0$,” defining the line as the intersection of the two planes given by those equations, but unless those equations are particularly simple, as in your example, there are less cumbersome ways to define a line in $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the locus of the points $(x,y,z)=(2,5,t)$ with $t\in(-\infty,\infty)$. It is indeed a (vertical) line.

Note that in any 3D line, not all three coordinates are known upfront.